# Triple DES algorithm in C?

Tags: c, security

Does anyone have code snippet for Triple DES algorithm in C ?

Thanks

Comment: At the worst case, grab some DES code, and follow the procedures here to turn that into triple DES: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_DES#Algorithm.

It might be worth considering, though, that there are *far* better ciphers out there for you to use. Please don't use DES.

Comment: thanks for the Tip and I will try to convey this but at this point that is not my call to use this or not. I need to implement this in C.

Comment: 3des is a very old aglo and was replaced by AES almost a decade ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple implementation in C & C++. Possibly simpler to use than libtomcrypt.

http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/misc/misc/cryptoapi/article.php/c8195

Comment: I would be wary of taking crypto algorithms from sample snippet pages like codeguru. For playing around it's find, but for securing your business use something more credible

Answer (score 4):

[OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/) is written in C and provides a 3DES algorithm.  It may not be as simple as some of the other suggestions, but it may be worth checking out.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [Crypto++](http://www.cryptopp.com/) library, they implement tons of algorithms including DES.

Answer (score 2):

[libtomcrypt](http://freshmeat.net/projects/libtomcrypt/) is a comprehensive crypto lib written in C, with a 3DES implementation.