# Encryption, decryption with objective c

Tags: objective-c

Can any one tell me how to encrypt and decrypt with *Rsa* and *3des* in objective c?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Triple DES algorithm in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2489926/triple-des-algorithm-in-c)

Comment: possible duplicate of [3DES Encryption in Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6478901/3des-encryption-in-objective-c)

Comment: See also [RSA encryption library or Classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7023163/rsa-encryption-library-or-classes)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/).

Comment: @user: Yes. It's very straightforward. Google around for examples and tutorials, try to implement it, and post a **specific** place where you have trouble if you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

As Objective-C is a true superset of C, you can use C libraries.

Comment: do you know how to use those libraries, ore where i can find ?

Comment: @user: Yes. It's very straightforward. Google around for examples and tutorials, try to implement it, and post a specific place where you have trouble if you get stuck. (shamelessly copied from @PengOne)